# How is it possible to create a single mx for multiple domains, just as Google does with its GSuite/Works service?

Tags: email, routes, record

How is it possible to create a single mx for multiple domains, just as Google does with its GSuite/Works service?

What we need, a server, a service??

I try a lot of posible solutions but no one let the same effect.
Any help will be appreciated.